# How to get all XML branches

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

How can I get all XML branches using Java.

For example if i have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
    <address>
        <name>Joe Tester</name>
        <street>Baker street 5</street>
    </address>
    <person>
        <name>Joe Tester</name>
        <age>44</age>
    </person>
</addresses>
```

I want to obtain the following branches:

```
addresses

addresses_address

addresses_address_name

addresses_address_street

addresses_person

addresses_person_name

addresses_person_age
```

Thanks.

Comment: "All XML branches using java"?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. It depends on what you intend to do with the data. Do you want to manipulate the nodes? Or just extract the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can get XML root, its' node and sub node names easily using any template engine. i.e Velocity, [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html) and other, [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html) have powerful new facilities for XML processing. You can drop XML documents into the data model, and templates can pull data from them in a variety of ways, such as with XPath expressions. FreeMarker, as an XML transformation tool with the much [better-known XSLT stylesheet](http://freemarker.org/fmVsXSLT.html) approach promulgated by the Worldwide Web Consortium (W3C).

FrerMarker support XPath to using jaxen,XPath expression needs Jaxen. [downlaod](http://jaxen.org/)

*FreeMarker will use Xalan, unless you choose Jaxen by calling freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.useJaxenXPathSupport() from Java.*

---

Just you need One Template, that will generate all XML branches according to input XML. really Put any XML on run-time to data model freemarker will process the template and  generate XML branches corresponding to that XML structure. If your XML structure will change then no need of to change your Java code. Even if you want to change the output then changes will comes in template file hence no need recompilation Java code.

Just change in template, get get changes on the fly.

**FTL File [One template for multiple XML document for creating xml branch names]**

```
<#list doc ['/*' ] as rootNode>
  <#assign rootNodeValue="${rootNode?node_name}">
  ${rootNodeValue}
<#list doc ['/*/*' ] as childNodes>
  <#if childNodes?is_node==true>
      ${rootNodeValue}-${childNodes?node_name}
     <#list doc ['/*/${childNodes?node_name}/*' ] as subNodes>
      ${rootNodeValue}-${childNodes?node_name}-${subNodes?node_name}
     </#list>
  </#if>
</#list>
</#list>
```

**XMLTest.Java for process template**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel;
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

public class XMLTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException, TemplateException {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setClassForTemplateLoading(XMLTest.class, "");
        config.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
        config.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER);

        Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              //load xml
        InputStream stream = XMLTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xml_path);
            // if you xml sting then then pass it from InputSource constructor, no need of load xml from dir
        InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
        NodeModel xmlNodeModel = NodeModel.parse(source);
        dataModel.put("doc", xmlNodeModel);
        Template template = config.getTemplate("test.ftl");

        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        template.process(dataModel, out);
        System.out.println(out.getBuffer().toString());

    }

}
```

**Final OutPut**

```
addresses
      addresses-address
      addresses-address-name
      addresses-address-street
      addresses-person
      addresses-person-name
      addresses-person-age
```

See doc for  [1.XML Node Model](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_expose_put.html) [2.XML Node MOdel](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_formal.html)

Download FreeMarker from [here](http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html)
Downlaod Jaxen from [here](http://jaxen.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you can extract data from XML and use it in Java. The one you choose will depend on how you want to use the data.

Some scenarios are:

1. You might want to manipulate nodes, order, remove and add others and transform the XML.
2. You might just want to read (and possibly change) the text contained in elements and attributes.
3. You might have a very large file and you just want to find some particular data and ignore the rest of the file.

For **scenario #3**, the best option is some memory-efficient stream-based parser, such as **SAX** or XML reader with the **StAX** API.

You can also use that for **scenario #2**, if you do mostly reading (and not writing), but DOM-based APIs might be easier to work with. You can use the standard **DOM** `org.w3c.dom` API or a more Java-like API such as **JDOM** or **DOM4J**. If you wish to synchronize XML files with Java objects you also might want to use a full *Java-XML mapping* framework such as **JAXB**.

DOM APIs are also great for **scenario #1**, but in many cases it might be simpler to use **XSLT** (via the `javax.xml.transform` **TrAX** API in Java). If you use DOM you can also use XPath to select the nodes.

I will show you an example on how to extract the individual nodes of your file using the standard DOM API (`org.w3c.dom`) and also using XPath (`javax.xml.xpath`).

**1. Setup**

Initialize the parser:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Parse file into a Document Object Model:

```
Document source = builder.parse(new File("src/main/resources/addresses.xml"));
```

**2. Selecting nodes with J2SE DOM**

You get the root element using `getDocumentElement()`:

```
Element addresses = source.getDocumentElement();
```

From there you can get the child nodes using `getChildNodes()` but that will return *all* child nodes, which includes text nodes (the whitespace between elements). `addresses.getChildNodes().item(0)` returns the whitespace after the `<addresses>` tag and before the `<address>` tag. To get the element you would have to go for the second item. An easier way to do that is use `getElementsByTagName`, which returns a node-set and get the first item:

```
Element addresses_address = (Element)addresses.getElementsByTagName("address").item(0);
```

Many of the DOM methods return `org.w3c.dom.Node` objects, which you have to cast. Sometimes they might not be `Element` objects so you have to check. Node sets are not automatically converted into arrays. They are `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` so you have to use `.item(0)` and not `[0]` (if you use other DOM APIs such as JDOM or DOM4J, it will seem more intuitive).

You could use `addresses.getElementsByTagName` to get all the elements you need, but you would have to deal with the context for the two `<name>` elements. So a better way is to call it in the appropriate context:

```
Element addresses_address        = (Element)addresses.getElementsByTagName("address").item(0);
Element addresses_address_name   = (Element)addresses_address.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);
Element addresses_address_street = (Element)addresses_address.getElementsByTagName("street").item(0);

Element addresses_person      = (Element)addresses.getElementsByTagName("person").item(0);
Element addresses_person_name = (Element)addresses_person.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);
Element addresses_person_age  = (Element)addresses_person.getElementsByTagName("age").item(0);
```

That will give you all the `Element` nodes (or branches as you called them) for your file. If you want the text nodes (as actual `Node` objects) you need to get it as the first child:

```
Node textNode = addresses2_address_street.getFirstChild();
```

And if you want the `String` contents you can use:

```
String street = addresses2_address_street.getTextContent();
```

**3. Selecting nodes with XPath**

Another way to select nodes is using XPath. You will need the DOM source and you also need to initialize the XPath processor:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

You can extract the root node like this:

```
Element addresses = (Element)xPath.evaluate("/addresses", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

And all the other nodes using a path-like syntax:

```
Element addresses_address        = (Element)xPath.evaluate("/addresses/address", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
Element addresses_address_name   = (Element)xPath.evaluate("/addresses/address/name", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
Element addresses_address_street = (Element)xPath.evaluate("/addresses/address/street", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

You can also use relative paths, choosing a different element as the root:

```
Element addresses_person      = (Element)xPath.evaluate("person", addresses, XPathConstants.NODE);
Element addresses_person_name = (Element)xPath.evaluate("person/name", addresses, XPathConstants.NODE);
Element addresses_person_age  = (Element)xPath.evaluate("age", addresses_person, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

You can get the text contents as before, since you have `Element` objects:

```
String addressName = addresses_address_name.getTextContent();
```

But you can also do it directly using the same methods above without the last argument (which defaults to string). Here I'm using different relative and absolute XPath expressions:

```
String addressName   = xPath.evaluate("name", addresses_address);
String addressStreet = xPath.evaluate("address/street", addresses);
String personName    = xPath.evaluate("name", addresses_person);
String personAge     = xPath.evaluate("/addresses/person/age", source);
```